Is it true that we can potentianally have far more than 2 wives in Jannah and that the number of wives we get depends on our number of hasanat?
I have heard several scholars say that the number of wives we get in Jannah depends on how much kheir we do in Dunya and that 2 wives are just the absolute minimum we can get. How valid are these claims?
